# Compare keys and values of different dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

If there are two dictionaries such that they share multiple keys with one another:

dictionary_1 = `{'apple': 0, 'berry': 2}`

dictionary_2 = `{'apple': 1, 'berry': 1, 'banana': 1}`

How can I compare them and determine:

- (1): if `dictionary_2` keys are **all** in `dictionary_1` keys

  - *False as 'banana' is missing*
- (2): and if values in `dictionary_1` are higher than the corresponding values in `dictionary_2`?

  - *False as the value of 'apple' is lower in dictionary_1*

Comment: Have you tried using `==`?

Comment: edited the "Pythonic" part. I thought in Python 3x they introduced something like "<=" to check for subsets/equality.

Comment: This seems more like 2 questions than one. (And no, you can't compare dictionaries, but you can use `dict.keys()` to return a set-like object, which you can compare.

Comment: @GeeTransit what do you mean by "you can't compare dictionaries" ? That's exactly what `==` is doing

Comment: You can't compare them. You can check if they're equal though. (Compare as in check which one's "bigger".)

Comment: @annataylor would you like to get `True` if the value in `dict_2` is higher?

Comment: @DeepSpace I would like to know if values in `dict_2` are all lower than the values in `dict_1` for the corresponding keys. If not, I'm okay with returning a "False", the question was referring more to the "How".

Comment: @annataylor, so you can use `==` to determine if both dicts have exactly the same keys and the same values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that `dictionary_2.keys()` is a subset of `dictionary_1.keys()` with the `<=` operator:

```
print(dictionary_2.keys() <= dictionary_1.keys())
```

And you can use `all` with a generator to check that the values in one dictionary are larger

```
all(dictionary_1[key] > dictionary_2[key] for key in dictionary_2)
```

Comment: I think it's possible to combine the checks with a smart use of `.get`

Comment: @DeepSpace You'd have to know which type the values are. If they're int, then 0 would be fine. Otherwise, it's hard to combine them without voodoo magic.

Comment: @GeeTransit Assuming the values are`int` or `float` (which is 99.99% the case) no voodoo is needed

Comment: @DeepSpace lol voodoo is reserved for the most edgiest cases (also what about negative values)

Comment: This is a great solution, one minor suggestion:
`all(dictionary_1[key] >= dictionary_2[key] for key in dictionary_1)` it is the solution for the 'question' but I get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: @DeepSpace I think the natural way to do it would just be to catch the `KeyError` that `all` would raise.